# RewriteCond to not rewrite a specific URI not working

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

I am working with a URL shortener (YOURLS) and I'm trying to have a certain page not directed to the link processing script. Here's the original `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN YOURLS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
# THE LINE I'M ADDING
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/InvalidLink\.html$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /yourls-loader.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END YOURLS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

I've added a new condition right before the `RewriteRule` line (commented out and pointed out above):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/InvalidLink\.html$
```

to have `http://example.com/InvalidLink.html` ignored. But this is making no difference. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That's the correct condition, however, where are you putting it?

Comment: Right before RewriteRule line

Comment: That already sounds correct, so there would seem to be something else going on here? Have you cleared your browser cache? If YOURLS uses 301 redirects then these will have been cached by your browser. Does `/InvalidLink.html` exist as a physical file?

Comment: I have cleared the cache. But InvalidLinks.html does not exist. Let me try that

Comment: The only thing with if `InvalidLinks.html` actually existed as an actual file (since it just looks like a real file) is that the existing directives would already exclude it from being rewritten.

Comment: You were right! Adding the file solved the problem. And I didn't need the new directive. But which part of the other directives is excluding InvalidLink.html? Is it the -f line?

Comment: "Adding the file solved the problem." - That isn't really a solution (unless `InvalidLinks.html` is meant to exist?) - it was just a test. If that works (and the browser cache was already cleared) then it implies that there was something wrong with the condition you were adding. Or are there any other directives? Or any other `.htaccess` files? Yes the `!-f` line would prevent any URLs that map to existing files from being rewritten.

Comment: Question updated. Added full `.htaccess`. I can't find any other `.htaccess` files. There is no parent directory anyway.

Comment: The lines after YOURLS directives are for forcing naked domain and were added by cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> # THE LINE I'M ADDING
> # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/InvalidLink\.html$
> ```

There is nothing "wrong" with the condition you are adding, providing the requested URL is exactly `/InvalidLink.html` (case-sensitive match), this `.htaccess` file is in the document root and the browser cache has been cleared before testing. So, this is still a puzzle. Try adding the `NC` flag - in case there is a mismatch in case, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/InvalidLink\.html$ [NC]
```

The fact that the *exception* "works" if you first create this file, in which case the first condition (`!-f`) prevents the rewrite happening, suggests that the file is being processed OK and your cache is clear. And that the above condition is at fault. However, from what you have posted it looks OK!?

An alternative to adding a condition to your existing rule, is to create a separate "exception" at the top of your file. So, instead of saying, "rewrite the URL if the request is not for `/InvalidLink.html`", we can add a separate rule that states "if the URL is `/InvalidLink.html` then stop here and do nothing more".

So, instead of your condition, include a separate rule at the top of your file:

```
RewriteRule ^InvalidLink\.html$ - [NC,L]
```

Note there is no slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* in per-directory `.htaccess` files. This will match `/InvalidLink.html` and prevent the following mod_rewrite directives from being processed. Ideally, the `NC` flag should not be necessary, however, I've included it "just in case".

---

This is really subsidiary to your main problem above...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
> ```

This *carbuncle* is what cPanel automatically adds before every `RewriteRule` when implementing the "Let's Encrypt" SSL cert. It's very messy and there is [much argument in the cPanel forums](https://features.cpanel.net/topic/ability-to-prevent-autossl-editing-htaccess-fles) requesting this be removed or changed. (Why they can't add a single code block/exception at the top of the file is a mystery.)

Anyway, in the interim, these directives can be safely removed (throughout the file) - they are not required (after the cert has been installed). This will simplify your directives, making the file more readable (and avoid any potential conflict). However, cPanel will later automatically re-add these directives when the certs are renewed (every 3 months).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
> ```

As mentioned above, the middle conditions can be safely removed. However, this canonical redirect is in the wrong place! It needs to be at the very top of your file, otherwise none of your shortened URLs will be canonicalised. In short, cPanel is not very good (unreliable) at editing the `.htaccess` file!

### Summary

Bringing all the above together, your existing `.htaccess` file can be rewritten as:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Canonical www to non-www redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Exceptions - avoid these URLs being rewritten
RewriteRule ^InvalidLink\.html$ - [NC,L]

# BEGIN YOURLS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /yourls-loader.php [L]
# END YOURLS
```

The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required. And the `RewriteBase` directive was superfluous. `.*` is the same as `^.*$`. Backslash escaping chars in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* is unnecessary (that's "typical cPanel").

Comment: You're right. www.example.com/keyword fails to redirect. YOURLS is expecting naked, but it gets www.

Comment: In the first RewriteRule, how does %1 match domain name? e.g., what if we had two conditions, each with its own groups?

Comment: Okay. I finally figured it out. What was happening was that, since InvalidLink.html did not exist, the server was redirecting to the 404 error page (not sure where it's defined), which also did not exist, and thus would be forwarded to YOURLS! I added an ErrorDocument directive and created a 404 page. Now InvalidLink.html shows the 404 page. Though in practice, a 404 will never happen. Everything not a file will go to YOURLS, which does a 302 to another error page.

Comment: `%1` is a backreference to the first captured group in the _last matched CondPattern_. So, in the above example, `%1` is a backreference to the `(.+)` subpattern in the `^www\.(.+)` _CondPattern_ (if it matched). If you had two conditions then the backreference refers to the _last one that matched_ (which isn't necessarily the last `RewriteCond` directive).

Comment: "...and thus would be forwarded to YOURLS!" - That really shouldn't have happened. It suggests that the `ErrorDocument` defined in the server config was misconfigured. A missing error document by itself wouldn't normally have caused this problem. But if the `ErrorDocument` specified an _absolute URL_ (instead of a root-relative URL) then it would have triggered an external redirect which would have resulted in the YOURLS script from answering the second (redirected) request. `ErrorDocument 404 default` would also resolve it. Bit of a guess but that seems to fit. Glad you sorted it! :)

Comment: The bad configuration is hardly surprising. This is the cheapest shared hosting I could find.